# How do I change the default text for "DEADLINE" and "SCHEDULED" in org-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I've been through the org-customize options but I may have missed it there. Can I change it somewhere in the org.el file? If so, where am I most likely to find that file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
`org-deadline-string` is a variable defined in `org.el'.
Its value is "DEADLINE:"

Documentation:
String to mark deadline entries.
A deadline is this string, followed by a time stamp.  Should be a word,
terminated by a colon.  You can insert a schedule keyword and
a timestamp with M-x org-deadline.
Changes become only effective after restarting Emacs.

You can customize this variable.
```

---

```
`org-scheduled-string` is a variable defined in `org.el'.
Its value is "SCHEDULED:"

Documentation:
String to mark scheduled TODO entries.
A schedule is this string, followed by a time stamp.  Should be a word,
terminated by a colon.  You can insert a schedule keyword and
a timestamp with M-x org-schedule.
Changes become only effective after restarting Emacs.

You can customize this variable.
```

Comment: Thanks! And I finally found org.el in usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/org-mode

Comment: To modify these variables, open up your `.emacs` file and put something like:  `(setq org-deadline-string "MY-DEADLINE:")` and `(setq org-scheduled-string "MY-SCHEDULED:")`.  You do not need to modify `org.el`.